# What's the right way to use managed Extensibility Framework in Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, mef

I've been working in an app that'll be fully extensive as it should implements a plugins system (quite a few contracts  in the same app)
My preoccupation is about using MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework)
I've find out a lot of tutorials, but somes seems to be outdated, and some are more confusing
In general

Whe have a way to do it by using these namespaces

- **System.ComponentModel.Composition**
- **System.Composition**
- **Microsoft.Composition**

And the latest methods I found in a Microsoft tutorial, **that use an AssemblyLoadContext and an Activator**
Here is the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support

I really like this last method because it's simple and I have a good working implementation already !

**I'm just asking myself: is it the right way to do it in an app that'll be widely distributed ? It sit secured enough ?**

Comment: IMHO the right way is to ditch MEF in .NET Core and use the generic host but I don't know what features it doesn't have which MEF would have had, if any. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I'll ditch into The Use generic-host

Comment: You can also use a custom AssemblyLoadContext with plugins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support